# Android: set activity orientation BEFORE onCreate, but not in manifest (HDMI plugged in issue)

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I can perfectly manage orientation change programatically, by using `setRequestedOrientation` in `onCreate`.

Everything works really fine, until I plug a HDMI cable. After this, the tablet "wants" to be in landscape mode. So when I open an activity, it shows first in "landscape" and then right after it shows in "portrait", (because I'm calling `setRequestedOrientation(variable_with_orientation_desired_by_the_user)` where `variable=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` in `onCreate` As you can "see", my app keeps rotating on every activity the user opens;

If I set the orientantion for activity in the manifest, this problem is partially gone, since the orientation in manifest is the same that the user has picked up. If they are different, the same behavior starts again.

I tried this, but with no success:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle saved)
{
    setRequestedOrientation(ScreenOrientation);
    super.onCreate(icicle);
}
```

So, is there any way to tell to android what orientantion it must create my activity, before it does create it? (But it cannot be in manifest)

Comment: Give your `setRequestedOrientation(ScreenOrientation);` after `super.onCreate(icicle);` And, what version of API are you using?

Comment: ... For real? He just said that's what makes the undesired behavior occur (because the activity is created and then only sets the orientation AFTER it is already displayed).

Comment: API: 13 (3.2). Also I had tried setRequestedOrientation(ScreenOrientation) after super.OnCreate. But  no matter where I call it, I get same behavior. The only thing that works is setting orientantion in manifest, but I get side effects, as I had described.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved it by setting screenOrientation to "behind" in manifest file:

```
        android:screenOrientation="behind"
```

Comment: That's not what this method is for. Please see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Comment: This is a good solution if you want your newly created activity's orientation as per the previously closed activity's

Answer (score 10):

I solved it using this declaration in manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="locked"
```

on every activity declared in manifest with this issue.

And keep using `setRequestedOrientation()` programatically to define if landscape or portrait orientation within `onCreate()` method,

Hope it helps!